# Smooth Scrolling not working in Chrome anchor

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, scroll, scrolltop

Hi there I cannot get smooth scrolling to work in Chrome. Works fine in other browsers. It will goto the anchor point but without smooth scrolling. I have also enabled scrolling as per chrome://flags/

Jquery:

```
jQuery('.arrow-down').on('click',function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash,
    jQuerytarget = jQuery(target);
    jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': jQuerytarget.offset().top - 60
  }, 1500, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
  });
});
```

Html:

```
<a href="#articleblock1" class="btn arrow-down"><div>SCROLL DOWN</div><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="line-height:15px;font-size:30px;"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi there I have figured this out.
I had overflow-x:visible on my body.

So I changed this to overflow:visible and this worked...not sure why though..?

Comment: Thanks! This helped me figure out that the overflow-y property I set on the body element was causing my own issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
body {    
    overflow:visible;
}
```

This worked for me. Put it in the CSS for the page. Chrome randomly stopped my jquery animate scrolltop code from working about a month ago. Glad I looked into this again as I couldn't find any answers before. Thank you RRowan!